# How to disable spam desktop notifications with 2020 Lubuntu onboard

Tags: lubuntu, firefox, notification

I receive spam notifications on a fresh install of Lubuntu 20.04 and I do not seem to be able to delete the right package.

The notifications (Mitteilungen der Arbeitsfläche; maybe “notifications of Desktop”) are lined up in the LXqt Settings menu tab and can be temporarily “deleted” in the notification's area in the lower right near the clock. But they are received and reappear again and go like this:

> Firefox: tragical Accident  Firefox: voice message.

How can I get hold of them and what have they to do with Firefox? They all start with the word “Firefox”. Should I read more system logs ;-)?

To be more precise, I need to receive system messages like battery, but I would like to cut off the Internet generated spam.

Comment: Do you have spam addons installed in Firefox?

Comment: Seems related: https://askubuntu.com/q/1084681/816190

Comment: Kulfy answered the question for me. In fact, it wasn't so freshly installed, and allowed some spammers to notify. +1 for Kulfy (Howto?)